# Visual Studio 2010 theme for Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, themes, visual-studio-2012

Is there anyway to change VS2012 theme look like VS2010?

Comment: This!  A million times, this!  Would also love to have some kind of addin to fix all of the context menus (right now they're pretty much worthless and utter crap) and fix all of the "new features" like that lame TFS Commit panel and that horrible Find dialog replacement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you install the theme editor, you get a huge improvement. The Blue theme is like VS 2010.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05

In addition to the [theme editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05) Andy mentioned, there is also a project in Codeplex that allows you to import VS 2010 icons into VS 2012

http://vsip.codeplex.com/

Comment: I used your link but I don't see a Blue theme - where can I get it?

Comment: @Daniel the blue theme was in the recent VS2012 Update 2 (free update)

Comment: There isn't a blue theme in your link