# Is there a way to make Visual Studio 2012 look more like Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

How can I alter the appearance of Visual Studio 2012 to make it more closely resemble 2010?

I am specifically concerned with making the colors match.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010 theme for Visual Studio 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216763/visual-studio-2010-theme-for-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a simple theme editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05) that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

The blue theme has been added back in Visual Studio 2012 Update 2, no extensions required.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2797912

[image]